# Is there a Magento v.1.x developer reference like is Codex for WordPress?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, magento-ce, documentation

Is there something like https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/ (Code Reference) for **Magento CE v.1.x** like this is for **WordPress**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the API references in the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/

Regarding code reference, I'm not aware of any *official* resource unfortunately.

Comment: @kanenas it can definitely help you but it's not official and it is very old, this website is related to Magento 1.7.0.2 so it's 3 years old, too deprecated to help I'm afraid

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a Magento 1.x Reference, but it's not quite the same as the one from WordPress.

The Magento 1.x reference is mostly about installations, upgrades, patches, and customizations:  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/.

I remember there was also once a documentation of classes and methods online. The most similar thing I could find right now is this: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/.

Anyway, as a Magento developer I'd say nothing's a better documentation than your local source code :-)